# Older php versions are getting auto installed

Tags: debian, apt, php7

I use Sury for Debian 10. Somehow I noticed, it's trying to install older versions and new versions. Is their any way, I can do something so that, apt-get update or apt-get dist-upgrade, doesn't install any packages besides php 7.4 ?

```
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php5.6-igbinary php5.6-memcached php5.6-msgpack php5.6-redis php7.0-igbinary php7.0-memcached php7.0-msgpack php7.0-redis php7.1-igbinary php7.1-memcached php7.1-msgpack php7.1-redis php7.2-igbinary
  php7.2-memcached php7.2-msgpack php7.2-redis php7.3-igbinary php7.3-memcached php7.3-msgpack php7.3-redis php7.4-igbinary php7.4-memcached php7.4-msgpack php7.4-redis php8.0-igbinary php8.0-memcached
  php8.0-msgpack php8.0-redis
The following packages will be upgraded:
  php-igbinary php-memcached php-msgpack php-redis
```

Comment: Does `--no-recommends` have an effect?

Answer (score 0):

`php5.6` and `php8` come from Sury repository. You can disable it:

```
sudo sed -i '/deb/s/^/#/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
sudo apt update
```

Then remove `php5.6*` and `php8*` packages (they will not recieve any update after removing Sury repository) :

```
sudo apt remove php5.6.
sudo apt remove php8.
```